# Adobe AIR mobile applications unit testing integration tests test automations

Tags: unit-testing, actionscript-3, continuous-integration, integration-testing, stage3d

We are developing mobile games based on Adobe AIR and stage3D technology.
Is there any possibility to do unit tests, integrations tests, UI testing in such applications?
Are there any continues integration tools? Jenkins plugins or anything else?

After some researches we've found several tools for AS3 Unit testing but most of them are supposed to be used with FLEX apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything supposed to be used with flex - can be also used with pure as3 (of course I'm not talking about flex-specific libraries/framesworks, but most of them like Robotlegs or Parsley are pure-as3/mxml compatible). 
So you can freely use Apache Flex compiler with Maven/graddle+flexmojos for CI, flexunit for unit testing (FlexPilot for UI tests, but not sure if it is ready-to use library for AIR, anyway it is open source, so you can adapt it to AIR)